# Two different category boxes in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want two category boxes for my articles. One box for topic-select and the other for project-select.

Do you know a PlugIn?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add custom taxonomies I think.

You can do that either by:

[a plugin called More Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/plugins/more-taxonomies/)

or

[by generating a new taxonomy in functions.php or create a plugin with the new taxonomy code](http://generatewp.com/taxonomy/)